# How do you initialize a parameter array in Verilog

Tags: verilog

This gives me an error saying that I can't assign a packed type to an unpacked type. I agree that the right side is an array of packed types, but why is the left side of the expression an unpacked type?

```
parameter [7:0] lsfr_taps [0 : 7]   = {8'd9, 8'd5, 8'd3, 8'h21, 8'd9, 8'd9, 8'd5, 8'd9};
```

Regardless the more important question is how do I inialize a two-dimensional array of multi-bit parameters in Verilog?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your initialisation is fine. You just need to add a `'` before `{`:

```
parameter [7:0] lsfr_taps [0 : 7]   = '{8'd9, 8'd5, 8'd3, 8'h21, 8'd9, 8'd9, 8'd5, 8'd9};
```

Comment: what does the '  mean?  also, does modelsim not support displaying two dimensional signals? it seems like it compiled fine, but I can't display it in modelsim

Comment: The apostrophe is used in array literals. I don't know if Modelsim supports 2D arrays for Verilog. I normally use ISim and VHDL.

Comment: If using Cadence NCVerilog for simulations, you will need to include the +sv switch when running the simulator from the command line. This is to treat the files containing the parameter definitions as SystemVerilog files